# How to increment Firebase subnodes

Tags: objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

in my Firebase database I have a node Users and a node Activities.
Inside the node Activities I have user ID subnodes. 
Inside them I need to add multiple activities, so I would add incremental subnodes activity1, activity2, activity3, etc..
refer to that particular user
[image: database structure]

I don't understand the best way to create incremental subnodes,
how can I count how many activities are inserted for a specific user, so I can add a child name with the incremental number of Activity

```
[[[[_ref child:@"activities"] child:currentUser.uid] child:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"activity%d", activitiesCount]] setValue:activity_data];
```

Comment: Firebase recommends against incrementing such sequentially, incrementing subnodes. See https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html